# minOccurs and maxOccurs on elements inside xsd:choice

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a root element `<a>` and its children `<b>, <c>, <d>`

Here's what I need:

- the child elements can appear in any order
- just 1 `<b>`
- more than 1 `<c>`
- 0 or 1 `<d>`

For example:

```
<a>
    <c />
    <b />
    <c />
    <d /> 
</a>
```

And here is my XSD:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:element name="a">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="b" />
        <xs:element name="c" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="d" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

But the `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` in `xs:element` may not work. When I run the example, I got an error:

> Element `<b>` is not allowed at this location under element `<a>`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here's what your XSD says:**  Within `a` you can choose one of the following options:

1. A single `b` element.
2. One or more `c` elements.
3. Zero or one `d` elements.

Your XML chooses option #2.  It doesn't get a second choice, and when the parser encounters the `b` element, it correctly reports the violation.

You might think you could fix this by granting multiple choices:

```
  <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
```

**This would now say:** Within `a` you can *repeatedly* choose one of the following options:

1. A single `b` element.
2. One or more `c` elements.
3. Zero or one `d` elements.

Your XML would now choose option #2, then option #1, then option #2, then option #3, then declare that your XML is valid.  Success?

No, not if, for example, you wish to ensure *only one* `b` element child because the choice itself is repeated, and option #1 can be repeatedly selected, each time allowing a single `b` element, but in aggregate, effectively allowing multiple `b` elements.

For this reason, `xsd:choice` and, in fact, ***XSD 1.0 in general cannot be used to represent your constraint.***

**Your options?**   Check this constraint in code outside of XSD, or use XSD 1.1's `xsd:assert`:

### XSD 1.1 Solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
           vc:minVersion="1.1">
  <xs:element name="a">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="b" />
        <xs:element name="c"/>
        <xs:element name="d"/>
      </xs:choice>
      <xs:assert test="count(b) = 1 and count(c) > 1 and count(d) >= 0"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I must use XSD 1.0 but your answer's helpful to me. Thanks.