# XSD describing arbitrary number of same child elements - xs:all / xs:sequence / xs:choice and cardinalities

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation, cardinality

I am trying to describe something like the following XML in XSD:

```
<componentDefinitions>
   <component id ="1"/>
   <component id ="2"/>
</componentDefinitions>
```

There are some additional constraints:

- there is only one `componentDefinition` block
- the `componentDefiniton` block can be empty or it contains an arbitrary number of `component` elements
- `component` elements may occur in any order

My solution to this is the following XSD:

```
<xs:element name="componentDefinitions">
   <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0">
         <xs:element name="component" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

However, this feels not correct since I am using `xs:choice` and at the same time I declare that it is ok to "choose" all contents of `xs:choice`.

Using `xs:all` instead seemed to be the correct solution for me but it is not allowed to set `maxOccurs="unbounded"`.

`xs:sequence` doesn't seem to be correct either since the `component` elements may occur in any order.

So here is my question: Is there any other (more simple) solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that there are multiple ways of specifying multiple child elements.

In your case, since only elements with the same name are possible children, the notion of *unordered* is superfluous. (BTW, in practice, unordered is commonly more trouble than it's worth anyway.)  What's commonly done in situations like this is to use `xs:sequence` around child `xs:element` with  `maxOccurs="unbounded"`.

### See also

- [The difference between <all> <sequence> <choice> and <group> in XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36286056/290085)
- [Meaning of minOccurs and maxOccurs for xsd:choice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28523597/290085)
- [minOccurs and maxOccurs on elements inside xsd:choice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28112263/290085)
- ["Unique Particle Attribution" violation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31719489/290085)
- [XML Schema minOccurs / maxOccurs default values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4821477/290085)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I see that I somehow was walking in a wrong direction with the unordered notion.